# If exists, UPDATE Table , Else Insert New Row In Table

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following line of query in my stored procedure. The purpose of this stored procedure is if the website link is already in the table, it will update the existing one. If not it will record as new  row from the other table' value.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_diffmod_v2`( 
IN para_diffmod LONGTEXT, 
IN para_link LONGTEXT)
BEGIN

IF EXISTS (
    SELECT website_link FROM diffmod WHERE website_link=para_link
    )THEN 
    UPDATE diffmod
    SET diffmod_content=para_diffmod
    WHERE website_link= para_link; 

ELSE
    INSERT INTO diffmod(website_id,website_link)
    SELECT id,link
    FROM   site_html
    Where  link=para_link;

    UPDATE diffmod
    SET diffmod_content= para_diffmod
    where website_link = para_link;

END IF; 
END
```

Let's say www.google.com is already recorded. When I call like:

```
CALL myDB.insert_diffmod_v2('test','www.google.com');
```

there is no problem and it do update the existing record.

But when I called the link which is not in the record (let's say Yahoo) like

```
CALL  myDB.insert_diffmod_v2('test','www.yahoo.com');
```

it didn't insert as new record in the table. Can I know why ?

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags. MySql **is not** sql server.

Comment: you can directly use on duplicate key update statement instead of above

Comment: Can i know how can i do ? I am quite new to MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Insert in to on duplicate key update example

"$" are parameters and make website_id,website_link as unique

```
INSERT INTO diffmod SET
        website_id = (SELECT id FROM   site_html Where  link=@para_link),
        website_link= $para_link,
        diffmod_content=$para_diffmod
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        diffmod_content=$para_diffmod
```

Comment: please check this and let me know

Comment: It show following error.
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column '$para_link' in 'field list' 0.000 sec

Comment: Please repalce those $marks with your parameters ( para_diffmod, 
and para_link )

Comment: i just add $ marks to indicate it you have to pass related values

Comment: please try it and let me know

Comment: The following error occur again. 
since my website_id from diffmod table is not null, it show the following error. Code: 1048. Column 'website_id' cannot be null 0.000 sec

Comment: website_id is getting from site_html primary key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116450/discussion-between-mahesh-madushanka-and-achilles).